# Magento 2 Update a product name using Rest API

Tags: magento2, product, api, rest-api

I got to update weight, qty, price and others field, but when I update the product name, on catalog list (admin) the product change the name, but when I enter on edit view, the product continue with the last name and on store search, the name continue the last too. But on API rest the name is updated.

I'm using POSTMAN, ex:
Request a PUT on `http://localhost/mystore/rest/V1/products/24-MB04`:

```
{

  "product" : {
        "name" : "TESTE PRODUCT NAME",
        "weight" : 200,
        "custom_attributes": [
        {
          "attribute_code": "MARCA",
          "value": "TEST"
        }
      ]

  }
}
```

The response was

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "sku": "24-MB04",
  "name": "TESTE PRODUCT NAME",
  "attribute_set_id": 15,
  "price": 32,
  "status": 1,
  "visibility": 4,
  "type_id": "simple",
  "created_at": "2016-06-26 15:22:24",
  "updated_at": "2016-06-26 15:22:24",
  "weight": 200,
  "extension_attributes": {
    "stock_item": {
      "item_id": 2,
      "product_id": 2,
      "stock_id": 1,
      "qty": 100,
      "is_in_stock": true,
      "is_qty_decimal": false,
      "show_default_notification_message": false,
      "use_config_min_qty": true,
      "min_qty": 0,
      "use_config_min_sale_qty": 1,
      "min_sale_qty": 1,
      "use_config_max_sale_qty": true,
      "max_sale_qty": 10000,
      "use_config_backorders": true,
      "backorders": 0,
      "use_config_notify_stock_qty": true,
      "notify_stock_qty": 1,
      "use_config_qty_increments": true,
      "qty_increments": 0,
      "use_config_enable_qty_inc": true,
      "enable_qty_increments": false,
      "use_config_manage_stock": true,
      "manage_stock": true,
      "low_stock_date": null,
      "is_decimal_divided": false,
      "stock_status_changed_auto": 0
    }
  },
  "product_links": [],
  "options": [],
  "media_gallery_entries": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "media_type": "image",
      "label": "Image",
      "position": 1,
      "disabled": false,
      "types": [
        "image",
        "small_image",
        "thumbnail"
      ],
      "file": "/m/b/mb04-black-0.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "media_type": "image",
      "label": "Image",
      "position": 2,
      "disabled": false,
      "types": [],
      "file": "/m/b/mb04-black-0_alt1.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "tier_prices": [],
  "custom_attributes": [
    {
      "attribute_code": "description",
      "value": "<p>Convenience is next to nothing when your day is crammed with action. So whether you're heading to class, gym, or the unbeaten path, make sure you've got your Strive Shoulder Pack stuffed with all your essentials, and extras as well.</p>\n<ul>\n<li>Zippered main compartment.</li>\n<li>Front zippered pocket.</li>\n<li>Side mesh pocket.</li>\n<li>Cell phone pocket on strap.</li>\n<li>Adjustable shoulder strap and top carry handle.</li>\n</ul>"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "special_price",
      "value": "32.0000"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "special_from_date",
      "value": "2016-06-26 15:22:24"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "image",
      "value": "/m/b/mb04-black-0.jpg"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "small_image",
      "value": "/m/b/mb04-black-0.jpg"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "thumbnail",
      "value": "/m/b/mb04-black-0.jpg"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "color",
      "value": "49"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "news_from_date",
      "value": "2016-06-26 15:22:24"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "custom_design_from",
      "value": "2016-06-26 15:22:24"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "category_ids",
      "value": [
        "3",
        "7",
        "4"
      ]
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "options_container",
      "value": "container2"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "required_options",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "has_options",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "url_key",
      "value": "strive-shoulder-pack"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
      "value": "2"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "activity",
      "value": "11,21,23,18"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "style_bags",
      "value": "27,29,30"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "material",
      "value": "32,33,36,38"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "strap_bags",
      "value": "61,62,65,66,67"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "features_bags",
      "value": "72,74,75,78"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "size",
      "value": "91"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "erin_recommends",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "sale",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "marca",
      "value": "TEST"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I enter on edit view product on catalog, the weight was changed,but the name didn't change!

Somebody can help me?

Thanks

Comment: hi @ranan cuoghi i would like to know do u have any idea to how add new attribute and value to the response object of this api rest/V1/products/24-MB04 ?

Comment: The following information might help others in a similar situation: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9874#issuecomment-312876969

Answer (score 1):

It's only a indexer cache. I use these commands:

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento indexer:reindex.

Comment: I am also have the same problem @Renan Cuoghi . Is it working after reindexing and deploying ?

Comment: Yes, it's only a cache. Reindex and clean cache.

Comment: No it's not working. I think it is Magento's bug

Comment: Set the attribute name to global on Store > Attributes > Product

Answer (score 1):

It works in default stores view, i think you should use

```
/rest/{store_code}/V1/products/{sku}.
```